# Deleting all Text including space and brackets around a keyword

Tags: python, text

I am beginner and tried a lot without success:

Example: `text = 'keep1.[keep2](keep3) keep4 [ (cut1 (cut2) KEYWORD cut3 (cut4)) cut5 ] keep5 (keep6)'`

Target-Output: `'keep1.[keep2](keep3) keep4 keep5 (keep6)'`

Task: Delete out all Text including space and brackets around the keyword.
There is at least one bracket around the keyword.
All other text and all brackets elsewhere should be kept.

Problem: We don't know how many brackets and which brackets [], {}, () are used around the keyword.

The first part I think is very easy, you find the postion of the Keyword:

```
keyword = "KEYWORD"
keyword_pos = text.find(keyword)
```

But now the problems start.
First I tried to count the open brackets of each type before the keyword.
If there are no corresponding closing brackets those need to be behind the keyword, right?
If there are 5 opening brackets of a specific type before the keyword and only three corresponding closing brackets the first opening bracket of that type that belong to the keyword is the forth opening bracket in this case I figured.
I think I need to loop but don't know how to do that.
Any ideas how to reach the target-Output?

Comment: Have you tried any regular expression?